# RecId generation has not been suspended for Table: ACCOUNTINGDISTRIBUTION.Suspend the RecId generation before reserving RecId. AX 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, project-management, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am getting this error when i add a line to Project PO and click on edit/save. 
RecId generation has not been suspended for Table: ACCOUNTINGDISTRIBUTION.Suspend the RecId generation before reserving RecId.

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not programming related, unless you're doing something custom. It's likely an AX 2012 bug that's been resolved with a hotfix.

It looks like `KB 2975755` solves it.

[image]